# Unable to install JDBC for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jdbc

I am using a Apple Mac with High Sierra.

I need to install JDBC for Node.JS. However, it gives the below error. Please suggest how this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

```
apples-imac:pConfMan parthamajumdar$ sudo npm install --save jdbc

> java@0.9.1 install /Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan/node_modules/java
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/parthamajumdar/anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v10.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.9.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.9.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/parthamajumdar/.npm/_logs/2018-09-20T11_09_00_132Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Looks like jdbc supports java 1.7 or
1.8 but you seems using java@0.9.1

Comment: This will likely not solve your issue, but avoid using `sudo npm`

Comment: Have you installed python

Comment: Yes, I have installed Python.

Comment: apples-imac:pConfMan parthamajumdar$ java --version
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

Comment: apples-imac:pConfMan parthamajumdar$ python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Python 2.7 and Java8 on my machine and now the issue has been solved. Thanks for your help.